# How to upload a file in background thread in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i want to upload a file from the photo chooser task in webdav server using background transfer request in windows phone 8 using "PUT" Method.Problem is file is appearing in server and Displaying with 0kb. if any one knew please post how to send the file stream as bytes with background tranfer request using background transfer request.Please if any one know help me......

Here is my code:

```
    private void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        progress.IsIndeterminate = true;
        progress.IsVisible = true;
        var photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
        photoChooserTask.Completed += PhotoChooserTaskCompleted;
        photoChooserTask.Show();
    }


  private void PhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {

        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        BinaryReader objReader = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto);
        filename = Path.GetFileName(e.OriginalFileName);
        MessageBox.Show("filename...." + filename);
        //MessageBox.Show(filename);
        sbytedata = ReadToEnd(e.ChosenPhoto);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        parameters.Add("photo", sbytedata);
        string   url = String.Format("{0:g}://{1:g}", _workingAccount.Protocol, _workingAccount.ServerDomain + _workingPath + filename);   
        UploadInBackground(url, parameters, _workingAccount,e.ChosenPhoto);
    }



    private void UploadInBackground(string url, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, Account _workingAccount, Stream stream)
    {
        // Check if there're already 5 requests.
        if (BackgroundTransferService.Requests.Count() >= 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please wait until other records have been uploaded.");
            return;
        }
        // Store the file in isolated storage.
        var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (!iso.DirectoryExists("/shared/transfers"))
        {
            iso.CreateDirectory("/shared/transfers");
        }
        using (var fileStream = iso.CreateFile("/shared/transfers/"+filename))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

        // Transfer the file.
        try
        {
            BackgroundTransferRequest request = new BackgroundTransferRequest(new Uri(url));
            request.Method = "PUT";
            var credentials = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(_workingAccount.Username + ":" + _workingAccount.Password);
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentials);
            request.Headers["ContentType"] = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", this._boundary);
            request.UploadLocation = new Uri("shared/transfers/"+filename, UriKind.Relative);
            request.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowCellularAndBattery;
            request.Tag = request.UploadLocation.ToString();

            OnBackgroundTransferStatusChanged(request);

            BackgroundTransferService.Add(request);

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to upload the file at the moment. Please try again later.");
        }
    }


       private void OnBackgroundTransferStatusChanged(BackgroundTransferRequest request)
    {

        if (request.TransferStatus == TransferStatus.Completed)
        {
            BackgroundTransferService.Remove(request);
            if (request.StatusCode == 201)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Upload completed.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occured during uploading. Please try again later.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually I can't see where you pass the stream into your request

Comment: How to do that please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue here is, the `stream.CopyTo(fileStream);` is not saving the data in the Upload location. You can verify this by using Windows Phone power tools and check if the file has been created and the data has been copied successfully at your specified upload location.